# Send alert on only successful schedule run

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have written below code to send data to AWS Lambda function whenever the scheduled job runs. The problem is it sends the alert whenever it fails 
 while running task(). How can I only send alert on successful run?

```
 $schedule->command('task:send')
            ->hourly()->appendOutputTo(storage_path().'/logs/task.log')
            ->after(function(){
                LambdaHelper::sendHeartbeatLambda("task");
            });
```

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to put the `LambdaHelper::sendHeartbeatLambda("task");` inside the actual command class if it does whatever it needs to do?

Comment: Yes. One way is to put it in the command class and call it. I am looking if Laravel has a better implementation than this.

Comment: Not from memory.  I assume you have looked in the docs?